# @SQL one time per class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

I'm writing some integration test using spring framework. I have different SQL scripts for different integration test classes. Something like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ...)
@Sql("classpath:sportCenter-test.sql")
public class SportCenterResourceIT {
    ...
}
```

Everything works perfectly except for the fact that the SQL script is executed before **each** test, instead of one time per class. I have already searched for some time the spring documentation but I was not able to find something related to such an option.

Could anybody give me an hint?

Comment: Do you have Before tag at your tests?

Comment: Please share your SportCenterResourceIT class with test methods no need what they indeed but i want to check is there any @Sql tag before test methods too.

Comment: @erhun There is no other ``@Sql`` tag in my test. The only one is at class level.

Comment: Do you want your SQL script to be executed once for the `ApplicationContext` loaded for your test? Or do you _really_ want your SQL script to be executed only once, before the test class?

Comment: I have solved this problem by using a script (at class level) to clear all the database entries. See [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-executing-sql).

Comment: hi, from the document, I did not  found any info of @Sql one time per class. In `Sql.ExecutionPhase` there are only `before test method` and `after test method`, without `before test class`, `after test class`

Comment: @zhuguowei I've found an workaround by clearing the database *after* each test. `@Sql` still executes *before* each test method.

Answer (score 10):

Adding the `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation at the class level will prevent any changes from `@Sql` scripts from persisting between tests. So your code becomes:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ...)
@Sql("classpath:sportCenter-test.sql")
@Transactional
public class SportCenterResourceIT {
    ...
}
```

This combination will result in the following:

1. Your `@Sql` script will run before each test
2. The test itself will run
3. Any database changes from steps 1 or 2 will be reverted at the end of each test

Comment: The `@Sql` statement will run but since we have `@Transactional` set, the statement will run in a transaction that's not commited. That is your test will not be able to access the data, your `@Sql` statement inserted or updated.

Comment: my sql script is inserting data. When 2nd test runs the sql is being loaded again which gives me a primary key constraint exception. How to prevent this?

Comment: in this way there is the side effect of executing the whole test in a transaction altering it's behavior; am I wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I use this way to resolve the problem:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql("classpath:sql/DataForRouteTesting.sql")
public class MyTest {}
```

Scripts are executed every time, but there are not conflict primary key.

Answer (score 4):

If we want to execute sql script one time per class, we can execute the script in setup method and set flag to true once the script is executed for one method so it does not execute again.
`
@Autowired
private DataSource database;

private static boolean dataLoaded = false;

```
@Before
public void setup() throws SQLException {
    if(!dataLoaded) {
        try (Connection con = database.getConnection()) {
            ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(con, new ClassPathResource("path_to_script.sql"));
            dataLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by putting the sql script in the *src/test/resources* folder with the name *data.sql*. This file is executed once at startup of each integration test. For this to work, you need to remove the @Sql annotation.

Comment: it's better than putting the script to each test class, but it doesn't solve all problems. On my case that script still executed multiple times.My script was create table, so I fixed the problem by adding a "if not exists" clause

Answer (score -4):

You can create an empty static method annotated with @BeforeAll and @Sql("classpath:sportCenter-test.sql")

```
@BeforeAll
@Sql("classpath:sportCenter-test.sql") 
public static void initSql() {
    
}
```

Comment: Spring won't see `@Sql` on a `@BeforeAll` method, only on test methods.